# Kendo Grid Popup Template bind data into second Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

I had simple [demo that I created here.](http://dojo.telerik.com/ApOXIDuS/6) What I want to achieve in `edit` mode, if `popup` '`yes`' second popup will appear and bind the value of `productName` in dropdownlist. Any idea how to open `2nd_popup_editor` using `kendo-template`?

another option I used `kendoWindow` call the `div` but it still not bind the `productName`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it. I use `edit` event to pass `e.model.ProductID` value to the input and call `kendoDropDownList`

[DEMO IN DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/ApOXIDuS/8)